# Como enviar um form com targe blank e redirecionar a pagina atual sem o crhome bloquear?

Tags: ajax, formulário, popup

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

Num form envio os dados via Ajax, no momento do retorno se:

```
if (json.retorno == true){
  $("#form_imprime").submit();
}
```

Se eu colocar um botão no form e enviar via o click desse botão ele abre outra janela e o navegador não reclama, mas se eu tentar enviar via ajax ele bloqueia dizendo que é popup, ai so vai abrir se o cara liberar o popup.

Acontece que não é bem um popup é uma nova pagina tanto é que pelo botão ele vai.

Sei que esse bloqueio de popup dos navegadores é normal, mas será que existe uma solução nesse caso, sem que o usuario tenha que intervir?

Tenho essa necessidade porque os usuarios que vão usar o sistema não tem experiencia e desbloquear o popup será um parto pra eles.

Em resumo eu preciso do seguinte:

```
0 - O usuario seleciona um horario e é enviado para outra pagina
1 - Nessa outra pagina esta o formulario entao gravar os dados do formulario (via ajax)
2 - Abrir um tela de impressão com os dados gravados
3 - Redirecionar a pagina do formulario para uma pagina anterior
```

Eu ja tenho esse sistema funcionando de um modo antigo, mas esta bem obsoleto, estou mudando pra ajax e encontrei essa dificuldade.

Comment: Realmente acho que não tem como fazer isso. Poderia fazer assim: após os dados serem gravados via ajax, vc mostra um botão "Imprimir" que ao ser clicado, abre a popup e ao mesmo tempo redireciona. Assim o navegador não irá bloquear. E vc nem precisa fazer uma requisição, basta usar os mesmos dados do formulário na janela de impressão.

Comment: Boa dica Sam, agora me surgiu uma outra necessidade, eu usava os modais do jquery e nele eu conseguia deixar a tela travada só dando opção do botão fechar, agora o designer usou modal do bootstrap, nele se o cara clicar fora do div da mensagem a mensagem fecha, ai o cara perde a opção de imprimir o que não pode, como travar para não fechar o modal se não for clicado no botão imprimir?